# Compiling project programmatically with specific framework

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Hello I want compile solution programmatically in C#. But problem is that if my solution is in framework 4.5 all is ok (compile perfect) but if my solution is in framework 3.5 are not working.

See my code:

```
    string compile(string sln)
    {
        ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();
        Dictionary<string, string> GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        BuildRequestData BuidlRequest = new BuildRequestData(sln, GlobalProperty, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);
        BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(new BuildParameters(pc), BuidlRequest);
        if (buildResult.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Failure)
        {
            throw new Exception("Compiling Error");
        }
    }
```

The error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joEP4.png)

Comment: Heard of Rolsyn yet? if not check it out. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I know Rolsyn but I need other method

Comment: I added picture with error.